# Error while installing Maven Integration for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, maven, m2eclipse

I'm trying to install Maven integration for Eclipse (Galileo) through `Install New Software` menu nad using the sonatype link

> http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/m2e

And getting following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.0.20101115-1102 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.20101115-1102)
>     Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Required) 0.12.0.20101115-1102 
>   (org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.20101115-1102) requires 'org.eclipse.emf.ecore.edit 0.0.0' but it could not be found

Tried to search for the missing bundle. But no success. :(

Any help?

Comment: m2e-users@eclipse.org is a more likely place to get useful help.

Comment: IF the answers here do not work for you, try this linked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968304/error-installing-maven-integration-for-eclipse-wtp

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In your install manager, check "Contact all updates sites..." and try again.  Since EMF comes from a different update site than M2Eclipse, M2Eclipse cannot be installed without the ability to check all update sites for required components.

---

UPDATE!

Since Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), m2e is now hosted at eclipse.org.  To install it, you just need to use the default Eclipse update site:

- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
- http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
- etc.

Comment: I additionally needed to add the helios update site http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/.

Comment: this worked link champ for me. I am using juno for my project.

Answer (score 7):

Are you using Eclipse CDT?  If so, you need to make sure you have the Java Development Tools installed as well.  Assuming you're using Helios, use http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/ as an update site and install the JDT tools from the list of features under "Programming Languages".  I had the same problem and that solved it for me.

Answer (score 5):

Since Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), m2e is now hosted at eclipse.org. To install it, you just need to use the default Eclipse update site:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno
http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
etc.
```

Hence, for getting maven in eclipse indigo please refer the answer highlighted in yellow color alongwith screenshot at below link

[eclipse indigo marketplace Maven Integration install error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480675/eclipse-indigo-marketplace-maven-integration-install-error)

Answer (score 3):

I have the same issue (btw, "contact all update sites" is default). I found this bugreport in eclipse bugzilla which kind of indicates that we are having an issue in the plugin itself.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330896

A workaround for me is to fall back to older versions of m2eclipse / m2eclipse extras / subversive integration. I used the following URLs:

- http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/m2e-0.10.2.20100623-1649/
- http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/sites/archives/m2e-extras-20101029/
- http://community.polarion.com/projects/subversive/download/integrations/helios-site/

Answer (score 1):

the majority of eclipse does not suport maven 3.5 iven 1.8. to install maven you must go to halp--install new software
Name:M2Eclipse
location: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4

for helios: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17793630)

Comment: The link indicated in the topic is an setup program to solve the error related above

Answer (score 0):

In order to install the new m2e (1.4) on helios, i had to uninstall all maven elements in eclipse and then, i could install m2e from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases".

Steps to uninstall existing maven elements ( from org.maven.ide.*) :

1. Click in Help in eclipse
2. Install New Software...
3. Click on What is already installed
4. Select all item from org.maven.ide.* (even if it's Required)
5. uninstall them all

Answer (score 0):

Another way of installing the Maven plug-in for Eclipse:

- Open Eclipse
- Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
- Search by Maven
- Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section
- Follow the instruction step by step
- After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:

  - Go to Window -> Preferences
  - Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel
  - Click on an existing project
  - Select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you checkmark contact all update sites during install to find request software before click to next of the  installation of Maven Integration for Eclipse & m2e-slf4j over logback logging (Optional).

i was facing same problem, right now it has solve by doing the above.
Hope this will helpful.