# Error installing Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven, eclipse-plugin, gwt-maven-plugin

I am trying to install the gwt-maven-plugin for Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2 (running on Ubuntu), following the instructions here:
http://uptick.com.au/content/getting-started-gwt-maven-and-eclipse

However, when I get to the step to install "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP", I get the following error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
> Software being installed: Maven Integration for WTP (Optional) 0.12.0.20110421-1500 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.20110421-1500)
> Missing requirement: Maven Integration for WTP (Optional) 0.12.0.20110421-1500 (org.maven.ide.eclipse.wtp.feature.feature.group 0.12.0.20110421-1500) requires 'org.maven.ide.eclipse.feature.feature.group [0.10.0,1.0.0)' but it could not be found

A [similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4297533/error-while-installing-maven-integration-for-eclipse) suggests to tick the "contact all update sites", but this isn't working for me. I have also added the Galileo & Helios update sites (in addition to Indigo) per a suggestion on this thread: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/206143/

Any other ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe m2eclipse has moved to eclipse.org as m2e, with a new update site at http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ and the newer Maven Integration for WTP (Incubation) feature from http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/ .  Try those.

See http://www.sonatype.com/people/2011/06/where-is-m2eclipse/ .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, using http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/releases/ to install Maven Integration for WTP helped. Thanks.