# eclipse indigo marketplace Maven Integration install error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

Use the marketplace in eclipse indigo to install Maven Integration for eclipse. But when confirming selected features, no matter I choose "Maven Integration for eclipse" only or with "slf4j over logback logging",the error remains :**Cannot complete the provisioning operation.  Please change your selection and try again. See below for details.**

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)

Missing requirement: async-http-client 1.6.5.20130531-2315 (com.ning.async-http-client       1.6.5.20130531-2315) requires 'package org.slf4j 1.6.2' but it could not be found

Cannot satisfy dependency:
From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
To: com.ning.async-http-client [1.6.5.20130531-2315]
```

A similar bug report has been delivered here http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/error/report/955795, remain unread, is it a bug of eclipse marketplace, or how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 14):

Indigo is almost 3 years old and 3 major releases behind. Can you update to the latest Eclipse instead?

If not, then try installing via *Help* > *Install New Software...*.

In the **Install** dialog, select the Indigo update site in the **Work with** drop-down. Let it load the list and then in the search field type "maven" and select the m2e feature.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/4297912
also, when it pulls up result,  type in "m2" in the search box. and that should pull up the maven plugin for eclipse

Answer (score 1):

go to this link download the file below this line (Install Eclipse plugins Automatically, if you have a clean install of 3.7 (Indigo) ) and extract the file in eclipse folder restart it and try install from marketplace

https://wiki.openmrs.org/display/docs/Step+by+Step+Installation+for+Developers

Answer (score 0):

You can try install Maven Integration from another way, not from Market Place.

Here another plugin, called Eclipse IAM, that contains Maven Integration and the instructions for the installation

[Eclipse IAM](https://code.google.com/p/q4e/wiki/Installation)

I hope this help you!

Answer (score 0):

Since Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo), m2e is now hosted at eclipse.org. To install it, you just need to use the default Eclipse update site:

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/kepler

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno

http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo

etc.